How do I work through the included error when I try to add my table for my database to my form?
I have set up my class to display my database data exactly like the example in SQLExplorer, and when I build the app I get an error when I try to add the table to the Center Pane of my container, using bC.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, table); to add the table. The error I get is "no suitable method found for add(java.lang.String,com.codename1.ui.table.TableModel)".
Has anyone had this same error when working through this class? I can't find any info on the internet. Thanks.
Edit 1
I have successfully created a separate screen class to add records to the database, so I have removed the tiers in this class for the "Select from" logic of the SQLExample class. Since I need to view all records, I have kept the remaining code from the logic build in the original order.
Not completed yet:
I need to remove unused imports, and I need to add my db and cursor cleanup before exit.
Here is my code:
public class Roster {

    Form rstr = new Form("Players", new BorderLayout());
    private final int counter = 1;
    Database db;
    Cursor cur;
    Container bC;
    Container leftPanel = new Container(new BoxLayout(Y_AXIS));
    String query = new String("Select * from players");

    public Roster() throws IOException {

        db = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("players.db");
        cur = db.executeQuery(query);

        
        int columns = cur.getColumnCount();

        if(columns > 0) {
            boolean next = cur.next();
            if(next) {
                ArrayList<String[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
                String[] columnNames = new String[columns];
                for(int iter = 0 ; iter < columns ; iter++) {
                    columnNames[iter] = cur.getColumnName(iter);
                }
                while(next) {
                    Row currentRow = cur.getRow();
                    String[] currentRowArray = new String[columns];
                    for(int iter = 0 ; iter < columns ; iter++) {
                        currentRowArray[iter] = currentRow.getString(iter);
                    }
                    data.add(currentRowArray);
                    next = cur.next();
                }
                Object[][] arr = new Object[data.size()][];
                data.toArray(arr);
                TableModel table = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, arr);

              rstr.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, table);
            }
        }
        rstr.show();
    }
//            Util.cleanup(db);
//            Util.cleanup(cur);
} 


You're adding the TableModel instance instead of the Table instance. This would be the correct code:
TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, arr);
Table table = new Table(model);
rstr.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, table);

Codename One uses a form of the MVC (Model, View, Controller) design pattern. MVC separates the model from the view, the model includes the data of the table but you can't add the data directly to the UI... E.g. if you want negative numbers drawn in red, how would the UI know to do that?
If you want to handle clicks on the data, how would the data know how to handle that or validate bad user input?
The Table class represents the view and controller which let you present and modify the data. Notice that it wraps the model which is a "clean" representation of the data.

The first error I experienced was caused because I wasn't creating the table properly. When I changed to the creation sequence Shai posted, I had a failure because I wasn't using the Codename One import for the Table Class. Always make sure to import Codename One classes into your code to prevent failure on unsupported Java features.
